# What happens when I deploy new kafka-connect cluster while file opened? (kafka-connect-hdfs)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using hdfs kafka connect cluster, as in distributed mode.

I set `rotate.interval.ms` as 1 hour, and `offset.flush.interval.ms` as 1 minute.

In my case, I thought the file would be committed when a new record with an hour interval with the timestamp of the first record came; and offset will be flushed every minute.

However, I wondered what will be happened when I restart the cluster when the file has still opened. I mean, what will be happened in below case?

1. The file was opened starting with a record with a '15:37' timestamp. (offset 10)
2. after 10 minutes, the kafka-connect cluster restarted.
3. (I thought step 1's file will be discarded in the memory, and not be committed to the hdfs)
4. When the new worker started, will the "new opened file" start tracking the record from offset 10?

Does `kafka-connect`/`kafka-connect-hdfs` keep us from losing our uncommitted records?

Due to the [official document](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-hdfs/current/overview.html#exactly-once-delivery), I thought `__consumer_offsets` will help me in this case, but I'm not sure.

Any documents or comments will be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consumer offsets topic is used for sink connectors, yes, and, if possible, the consumer will reset to the last non-committed offsets.

I think the behavior might have changed some time ago, but the HDFS Connector used to use a write-ahead log (WAL) to temporarily preserve the data the it was writing to a temporary HDFS location before the final file was created.